# Interpolating between two data sets drawn from standard normal distribution

Tags: statistics, interpolation

Consider the standard normal distribution $Z(0,1)$. Assume $x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,\cdots, y_n)$ are two samples of size $n$ from $Z$. What are ``sensible'' ways (if any) to interpolate between $x$ and $y$? Of course one could use linear interpolation, $u_\alpha =(1-\alpha)x+\alpha y$, but I am looking for interpolants that are close to what might be samples of $Z$, while also creating a path of short length from $x$ to $y$.

Edit:

Here is a possibility:

Suppose the interpolating points are $P=\{p^1,\cdots, p^k\}$. Each can be put to a normality test to see how close to a sample of size $n$ of $Z$ they are. We get a set of abnormality scores $ a_1,\cdots, a_k$, with a total $A=a_1+\cdots+a_k$.

We also calculate the length of the path $L=d(x,p^1)+d(p^1,p^2)+\cdots+d(p^k,y)$. And perhaps a measure $R$ of the roughness of the path. Now we have a total $T=A+L+R$ (perhaps after a normalization to make the components comparable). The set of $P$'s that minimizes $T$ will be the interpolating set of points.

Is there a practical way of approximating $P$?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are asking for here -- you are generating two vectors in $R^n$ whose components are iid $N(0,1)$. So these vectors will exhibit spherical symmetry in terms of density level sets in $R^n$. What is the interpolation trying to do? What do you mean by "might be samples from Z"? You need to provide  more precise constraints on the allowed paths between $x,y$.

Comment: @Bey  I understand the question is somewhat vague. I am paraphrasing a question that was put to me.

Comment: But what do you mean here: “ I am looking for interpolants that are close to what might be samples of ”?

Comment: @Bey We can take the interpolating points and put them to a normality test to measure how close to a sample of Z they look like. Get an abnormality score. Add them up. Add the length of the path to it. Then minimize the total. Except this looks computationally prohibitive. And ad hoc.

Comment: Ok — can you write these details in the post, using math?